# Godot Tapping Game Advice

Tags: godot

I want to create a reaction game like the 'Circle Shot' from Aim Lab for mobile. So instead of shooting, user will be required to tap the circles appearing. If I were to make it as simple as possible, what node should I use for the circles? a sprite or a texture button?

I also would like to ask how to contain the circles so they do not spawn out of bounds. Do I use a grid container or something else?

Comment: Using `TextureButton` will be easier to prototype, however it is a `Control`, you may or may not want to use `Node2D` (I'm assuming this is a 2D game) depending on what you want to create. "how to contain the circles so they do not spawn out of bounds" you just don't spawn out of bounds. In all honesty, go and try to make it, when you run into problem come back and ask.

Comment: If I were to not use a singleton, where do I put my functions such as spawnCircle() and popCircle() in?  Should I place it in the script that is attached to the parent node of the scene?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Why?

This question is weird in some ways:

1. Why using **TextureButton**?
   TextureButton is actually a **Control** node and a Control node is used mainly for **UI** scenes.
   I'm not saying that this is not possible to use TextureButton to create a game and not create UI but I mean this is not the best way to do this.
2. Why using **Sprite**?
   You can not use an Sprite for that, cause you can't click on it.
   Sprites use cases are for creating animation, just having a pic on scene, maybe background use cases and etc.

### So What?

What I mainly suggest is using:

1. **KinematicBody2D**: This node is a **Node2D** type and you can so easy move it across the screen with a script attached to it.
   You can simulate physics for it and move it around with functions like **move_and_slide()**, **move_and_collide()** and etc.
2. **RigidBody2D**: This node is also a **Node2D** type and you can so easy simulate a mass, gravity and weight for it to have an object that can't move by itself but can move by environmental forces(like a punch, gravity or ...).

### How?

Each of these Nodes are inherited from a **CollisionObject2D** node that has 3 signals:

1. **mouse_entered()**: Emitted when the mouse pointer(in this scenario, The Finger) enters any of this object's shapes.
2. **mouse_exited()**: Emitted when the mouse pointer(in this scenario, The Finger) exits all this object's shapes.

By these signals you can understand if characters finger is inside the circle or not.
**Important Note**: I did not actually tested this by myself cause I do not develop on mobile devices but by my little experience on creating games for pc's, these should do.

### Advice

Also always have an eye on the latest stable godot [documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/) and see if there is any other better solutions or better nodes for handling your situation.

Comment: Do you think RigidBody2D will be easier to use than Texture Button if the circles I'm planning to create is not moving at all. It will just appear and stay there until the timer runs out or if the user taps it.

Comment: If this is what you are looking for and you do not want to move the circles at all, TextureButton will satisfy your needs but maybe you find some complexity on your way cause TextureButton is a Control node and using a Control node to create a whole game based on it, is not the best way to create a game but as I said, it is possible to do. hope you handle the situation and have fun coding. @newbie112

Comment: @newbie112 If you just accept my answer, that will make me happy. :)